# "data is null" when using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have issue with the last string in my code.

This is my code:

```
private void comboLname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string conn = "Data Source=srv-db-02;Initial Catalog=rmsmasterdbtest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=*****";
            string Query = "select * from RMSCRMTest.dbo.sales where LastName= '" + comboLname.Text + "' ;";


            SqlConnection Myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, Myconn);
            SqlDataReader Reader;
            try
            {
                Myconn.Open();
                Reader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    string ID = Reader.GetInt32(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID")).ToString();
                    string AccountNuber = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("AccountNumber")).ToString();
                    string Time = Reader.GetDateTime(Reader.GetOrdinal("Time")).ToString();
                    string Deposit = Reader.GetDecimal(Reader.GetOrdinal("Deposit")).ToString();
                    string slastname = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("lastname"));
                    string sstatus = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("status"));
                    txtid.Text = ID;
                    txtacnum.Text = AccountNuber;
                    txttime.Text = Time;
                    txtdeposit.Text = Deposit;
                    txtlname.Text = slastname;
                    txtstatus.Text = status;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Myconn.Close();
            }
}
```

This issue shows since I added another column to my table and created string to the column
string

```
sstatus = Reader.GetString(Reader.GetOrdinal("status"));
```

The error I get is

> data is null this method or property cannot be called on null values

The other strings working just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to check the nullable fields using the `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull` method:

```
int statusIndex = Reader.GetOrdinal("status");
string sstatus = Reader.IsDBNull(statusIndex) ? null : Reader.GetString(statusIndex);
```

Comment: I replace my line with yours and I got "unable to cast object of type 'system.Int32' to type system string'"

Comment: Sorry I didn't do it right let me check again and will get back to you thankss

Comment: it is working thank you very much, Please can you explain why I had to add int as this column is varchar and I'm really new to this world

Comment: You are seeing if the data at that index is null. And if it is, then return null. Otherwise, get the string.